# Could A Solidity Developer with Binance Chain Familiarity Explain This?

Tags: solidity, payable

I am a large holder of a certain token. We recently notice that one wallet where liquidity was being sent regarding 8% of transactions was unwrapping and selling those tokens. We confronted the developer. Right around the same time, we noticed a strange change to the contract. It was not verified, so I decompiled it with ByteCode. Here is the decompiled version. If you would be willing to help us dig further on telegram and potentially catch a scammer in the act, let me know. I'm not sure if this is enough info without the original contract which I can also post if that is helpful. Looking for any information you can provide. Thank you.
[image]

Comment: You have to post the contract's address and your post does not include the decompiled bytecode, only a small screenshot.

Comment: Here is the contract:
https://bscscan.com/address/0x83cb33e78bf03fc07a6370e45a2c406222f0d410#code

Here is the change to the contract:
https://bscscan.com/address/0x7dd8f8bf4c66de045ec6d15133e2df4d2d01f287#code

As you can see, it appears to only be that one line of code involving a fallback and payable as shown in the screenshot.

One person we spoke to feels it has something to do with transaction fees and is not malicious.

Comment: The second contract (0x7dd) does not seem to have anything to do with the first one (0x83C). The token contract has fee on transfer (burns) and other feather like that. Are you sure that you are not seeing just tokens being burned what a transfer is made?

Comment: There is 8% of all transactions burned and sent to a wallet and wrapped into liquidity tokens yes. That has been happening. We were just wondering if the second contract made any changes to the first or what it does generally, if anything. It appears it doesn't even change the first.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the intent of the question is to explain the part of the decompiled code in the image (and not the rest of the contract):

The function you've posted is not malicious. A `fallback` function is called whenever ETH is sent to the contract (but not in the context of a function call) - you can read more about them [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/contracts.html#fallback-function). By making a `fallback` function such as this one with `revert` inside, it means that if someone tries sending ETH to the contract, the tx will fail.

This is sometimes used to prevent ETH from getting "stuck" in a contract. If someone sends ETH to a contract that doesn't have a function for sending ETH, there's no way to get the funds out. In order to prevent loss of ETH, this fallback will cause any direct ETH transfer to fail.